# Print bash history onto terminal from shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have basically mounted a disk image and am required to analyse it by printing various bits of information to the terminal via a bash script.

I understand you can print your bash history by typing 'history' into the command line and hitting enter.

I need the result to be the same, however;

1. it needs to be executed within a bash script
2. it needs to be the bash history for the disk image, not my computer

Big thanks for all that help

Comment: You can look at `.bash_history` in the user's home dir in the disk image

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am unable to locate the .bash_history folder on the disk image file. Is there a command I can do to find it? Thanks

Comment: Since it starts with a `.`, it's hidden by default. You can show hidden files with `ls -a` or search for it with `find /yourpath -name '.bash_history'`

Comment: See my answer, did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so basically you do this:

1. Make sure the disk image is mounted
2. Open up a terminal
3. Change directory into the disk image using `cd /path/to/your/disk_image`
4. Find the file that houses the BASH history (biggest chance it is a hidden file so list them all via `find /path/to/your/disk_image -type f -iname ".*" -ls`.
5. You could (if you want) append its contents to the current in-memory history list via `history -r /path/to/your/disk_image/.bash_history`
6. Create a BASH script and simply put `VAR1=$(cat /path/to/your/disk_image/.bash_history)` to save the contents of the file to your script so you can use it from within the BASH script.